# If statement with three true conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

This is my data:

```
Year1 <- c(2015,2013,2012,2018)
Year2 <- c(2017,2015,2014,2020)
my_data <- data.frame(Year1, Year2)
```

I need an if statement that returns 1 when year 1 equals 2015 OR 2016 AND year 2 is greater than 2016. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    my_data <- my_data %>%
mutate(Y_2016=ifelse(my_data$Year1==2015|2016 & my_data$Year1>2016,1,0))
```

But this does not work and only seems to check the condition if Year 2 is greater than 2016, since it returns 1 even for the last row when Year 1 is 2018 and Year 2 is 2020.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `transform(my_data, Y_2016 = +(Year1 %in% c(2015, 2016) & Year2 > 2016))`

Comment: @Park's answer/approach preferred, just to note the reason the `|` isn't working here is because you need to specify the variable for each condition in the "or" - i.e., `my_data$Year1==2015 | my_data$Year1 == 2016` - though again the `%in%` function is usually a more elegant way to go in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Instead of `my_data$Year1==2015|2016`, use `%in%` like `my_data$Year1 %in% c(2015,2016)`.
2. Typo in `my_data$Year1>2016`
3. As you using `dplyr` you do not need to specify every variable with `$` like `my_data$...`

```
    my_data%>%
      mutate(Y_2016=ifelse(Year1 %in% c(2015,2016) & Year2>2016,1,0))

      Year1 Year2 Y_2016
    1  2015  2017      1
    2  2013  2015      0
    3  2012  2014      0
    4  2018  2020      0
```